# Cannot use lambda expression when filtering or mapping dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have piece of code below.
The problem is that the lambda function inside filter() cannot parse the dataset into [TransactionReportData].
Did anyone face it before and can help with it?

```
val transactions = spark.read.format( "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") .option(uri, uriIn) .option("pipeline", s"[{ $$match: { duplicate: { $$ne: true }, time : { $$gte : $start, $$lt: $end }} }]") .schema(schema).load.as[TransactionReportData].persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val attributedTransactions : Dataset[TransactionReportData] = transactions.filter((transaction: TransactionReportData) => {transaction.type == 2 || transaction.type == 1})
```

It throws:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 2267, Column 82: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, double, double, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, long, java.lang.String, scala.Option, scala.Option, long, java.lang.String, scala.collection.Seq, scala.collection.Map, scala.collection.Seq, scala.collection.Seq, com.something.models.package$OsBrowserInfo, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String"; candidates are: "com.something.models.package$TransactionReportData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, double, double, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, long, java.lang.String, scala.Option, scala.Option, long, java.lang.String, scala.collection.immutable.List, scala.collection.immutable.Map, scala.collection.immutable.List, scala.collection.immutable.List, com.something.models.package$OsBrowserInfo, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)”
```

and

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 2262, Column 81: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, double, double, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, long, java.lang.String, scala.Option, scala.Option, long, java.lang.String, scala.collection.Seq, scala.collection.Map, scala.collection.Seq, scala.collection.Seq, com.something.models.package$OsBrowserInfo, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String"; candidates are: "com.something.models.package$TransactionReportData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, double, double, double, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, long, java.lang.String, scala.Option, scala.Option, long, java.lang.String, scala.collection.immutable.List, scala.collection.immutable.Map, scala.collection.immutable.List, scala.collection.immutable.List, com.something.models.package$OsBrowserInfo, boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)"
```

and about 2000 java-compiled LOCs

but I tried

```
import spark.implicits._
val attributedTransactions : Dataset[TransactionReportData] = transactions.filter($"`type`" === 2 || $"`type`" === 1)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting error when TransactionReportData is being instantiated and not for filter. 
I tried case class and used it in a filter function for  Dataset as below it worked perfectly fine for me. Putting it below for your reference. I tried all of this in a spark-shell.

```
case class emp(id:String,emptype:String)
val list=List(emp("1","fulltime"),emp("2","contractor"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)
val ds=rdd.toDS
ds.filter((x:emp)=> x.emptype =="contractor").show // One approach
ds.filter(_.emptype == "contractor").show          // Another approach
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this job inside docker and it worked properly lol. Use the same jar, env, config, spark_version. The only issue I think now is JVM, but have no evidence  to prove.